# Inkscape alternative for scientific schematic figures

Tags: drawing, graphic-design, scientific-computing

I would like to produce something like the figures below. So far I have been using Inkscape, which is a bit laborious sometimes. As an alternative, sometimes Microsoft PowerPoint hasn't worked that bad. 
Are there other alternatives that come to your mind?

[image] [image] [image]

References for the figures: http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.591
http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.81.051908
http://www.stephenjdecamp.com/

Comment: I think you should use some vector graphical application eg.: Adobe Illustrator or CorelDraw. As I know professionals use them too.

Comment: please be more specific... what features do you need? since *Inkscape* (vector graphics) and *Powerpoint* (presentations) are two completely different programs. - for example suggesting *Libreoffice Impress* won't make much sense...! -- or at least tell us what the mentioned programs lacks.